# Spring REST API Security, When to use OAuth and When to use Spring Security?

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm developing Spring REST application for Android & iOS Clients. And there is a web client as well. I can use spring security to implement web client. But for android and ios app should I still use spring security? or is it better to implement OAuth? Since I'm not allowing my APIs to access 3rd party, is it really worth to implement OAuth? cz I myself develop Android & iOS clients.

Comment: Spring Security suppors OAuth why drop Spring Security and try to reinvent the wheel by yourself?

Comment: Do you want to protect your rest Api or your client apps (web, iOS, Android)?

Comment: I want to protect my REST API. currently I'm using SSL, in addition to that i'm gonna use OAuth with spring security, do I really need to implement OAuth? cz I'm not exposing APIs 3rd party to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of OAuth is to enable clients to access resources on behalf of 3rd parties, without revealing 3rd party credentials to the clients. In your case you have complete control over your users both at client side (Android/web/iOS) and resource side (the Spring REST application), therefore you wouldn't benefit from the main concept behind OAuth.

Unless you have requirements which prevent you from storing passwords at your clients, or unless you plan to be expanding usage of your APIs to other applications which shouldn't be able to obtain credentials of your users, you will be fine with using SSL/TLS + e.g. HTTP-Basic authentication and spend the saved time on making the application itself better.

Of course you must make sure to never send the credentials over an unecrypted channel, but the same applies to OAuth Bearer tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This answer simply explains when to use OAuth and when to use HTTP Basic authentication. In my case decided to go ahead with HTTP Basic authentication, as you said my app wouldn't benefit from the main concept behind OAuth. Thanks.